# DATE TIME Conversions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very new to SQL, well not so new any longer.

I'm just curious... I just would like to know why I have seen inconsistencies in `Date` conversions.

Why do some developers use:
`SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)`  == > this makes sense to me: 
`05/24/1987 10 chars`

Some use:

`SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(12), GETDATE(), 101)`

Can someone break this down? Are we just being careful, maybe, with leading/trailing spaces?

And I have even seen:

`SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(15), GETDATE(), 101)`

Why anyone would use this?

Comment: Which DBMS? Looks like SQL-Server?!

Comment: to truncate the output

Comment: Why don't you ask the person who used it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the data as a string to be as slim as possible, one could use this date to string command:

```
CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 20)
```

I don't see any good reason for using 101 instead of 20 at the end there.

If you want the data as slim as possible and it doesn't matter if the date is still a date (and not a string), one could use this command:

```
convert(date, GETDATE())
```

Ultimately, the end result is the pretty much the same for each -- a unique value per date.

I guess some developers might include trailing spaces for some personal expression or something -- or, like, doing weird things to more easily track down what code they wrote, maybe.

---

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) as Datestamp_CHAR10_101
, CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 20) as Datestamp_CHAR20_20 -- imho, the best way to store a date as a string
, CONVERT(CHAR(12), GETDATE(), 101) as Datestamp_CHAR12_101
, CONVERT(CHAR(15), GETDATE(), 101) as Datestamp_CHAR15_101
, CONVERT(CHAR(23), GETDATE(), 121)  as Datestamp_CHAR25_131
, DATALENGTH(CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)) as DATALENGTH_CHAR10_101 -- 10
, DATALENGTH(CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 20)) as DATALENGTH_CHAR20_20 -- 10
, DATALENGTH(CONVERT(CHAR(12), GETDATE(), 101)) as DATALENGTH_CHAR12_101 -- 12
, DATALENGTH(CONVERT(CHAR(15), GETDATE(), 101)) as DATALENGTH_CHAR15_101 -- 15
, DATALENGTH(CONVERT(CHAR(23), GETDATE(), 121))  as DATALENGTH_CHAR25_131 -- 23
, GETDATE()
, convert(date, GETDATE()) -- Probably the best answer. Why change the data to a string ..?
, DATALENGTH(GETDATE() ) -- 8
, DATALENGTH(convert(date, GETDATE()) ) -- 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

You will see that the century (yyyy) or (yy) is your length variance.

With 101; the length is 10, Make a convert(12 or convert(15 is not necessary

Here is a good sample :  http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

1. SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 1)
2. SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)